# jquery Missing Manual tutorial: replaceWith() into hover() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-hover, replacewith

I'm dealing with the jquery Missing Manual (O'Reilly) tutorial of page 215.

Given this HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Rollover Images</title>
<link href="../_css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
#gallery img {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
}
</style>
<script src="../_js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="my_scripts/rollover.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<header>
    JAVASCRIPT <span class="amp">&amp;</span> jQUERY: THE&nbsp;MISSING&nbsp;MANUAL
</header>
<div class="content">
    <div class="main">
        <h1>Rollover Images</h1>
        <p>Mouse over the images below</p>
        <div id="gallery"> <a href="../_images/large/blue.jpg"><img src="../_images/small/blue.jpg" width="70" height="70" alt="blue"></a> <a href="../_images/large/green.jpg"><img src="../_images/small/green.jpg" width="70" height="70" alt="green"></a> <a href="../_images/large/orange.jpg"><img src="../_images/small/orange.jpg" width="70" height="70" alt="orange"></a> <a href="../_images/large/purple.jpg"><img src="../_images/small/purple.jpg" width="70" height="70" alt="purple"></a> <a href="../_images/large/red.jpg"><img src="../_images/small/red.jpg" width="70" height="70" alt="red"></a> <a href="../_images/large/yellow.jpg"><img src="../_images/small/yellow.jpg" width="70" height="70" alt="yellow"></a></div>
    </div>
</div>
<footer>
    <p>JavaScript &amp; jQuery: The Missing Manual, 3rd Edition, by <a href="http://sawmac.com/">David McFarland</a>. Published by <a href="http://oreilly.com/">O'Reilly Media, Inc</a>.</p>
</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The tutorial is asking me to rollover the "large" images onto the small ones shown when the page initially loads.
The book proceeds in completing the forementioned task using a regular expression trick.

I don't want to complete this tutorial in the suggested way and I tried to figure out how I can perform the image rollover correctly by only using the replaceWith function inside the hover function.

I came up to this script (rollover.js):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#gallery a').each(function(){

        if ("$(this)[href*='large']" ){

            $('<img>').attr('src',$(this).attr('href'));

            }       
        });


    $('#gallery img').each(function(){

        var $oldimage = 0;

        $(this).hover(

        function(){

            $oldimage = $(this).replaceWith('<img src=' + $(this).parent().attr('href') + '>');
            console.log('old image' + $oldimage);

        }
        ,
        function(){

            $(this).replaceWith('$oldimage');
            console.log('comeback' + $oldimage);

        });

    });

}); // end ready
```

The result is that the first part (mousenter) of the hover function is correctly performed, but the second part (mouseleave) of the hover function seems to not be executed at all, even the console.log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by what you're doing in the first handler. In using `replaceWith`, you are altering the DOM (specifically the img element you have bound the hover event to) and affecting the event bindings in place.

Instead of using `replaceWith`, you should use the `attr` function to update the image src attribute.

**EDIT**

Try this, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/3dr7n8b7/1/

Comment: The point is that the book completes the tutorial as you suggested, using attr function and a regular expression trick, but as I don't want to proceed like that, I'm asking around if there is a way to complete the task using the replaceWith function.
Can you help me with that?

Comment: Why are you so intent on using replaceWith? Why remove the element from the DOM and add it again, when only an attribute needs updating?

Comment: Why? Because I'm experimenting how to correctly use this function in combo with hover, that's why.

Btw I tried your changes, and now the large images correctly replace the small ones and get resized, but the second part of the hover function still don't execute; I mean the colored large image get stuck in the container even if the mouse left that image.

Comment: You could use it in combination with the hover listener, but not on the element which is bound to the hover event. That's why you're getting problems. You could try binding the hover event to the parent <a> and using replaceWith to update the <img/> within...

Comment: I'm going to try to bind the hover to the <a> like you said.
Btw the solution you suggested in jsfiddle doesn't work, I made some changes to get it to work properly.
http://jsfiddle.net/Gargaroz/3dr7n8b7/2/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#gallery a').each(function(){

        if ("$(this)[href*='large']" ){

            $('<img>').attr('src',$(this).attr('href'));

            }       
        });


    $('#gallery img').each(function(){

        var $oldimage = 0;

        $(this).on('mouseover',

        function(){

            console.log($(this));

            $oldimage = $(this).attr('src');
                $(this).replaceWith('<img src=' + $(this).parent().attr('href') + '>');
               // $('#gallery img').each(function(){
                       $(this).on( "mouseleave", function(){

                           $(this).replaceWith('<img src=' + $oldimage + '>');
                           console.log('comeback' + $oldimage);

                       });

          //  });
            console.log('old image' + $oldimage);

        });

    });

}); // end ready
```

Comment: Tried, but nothing happens, the small images don't show.